# Why does the latex-code for questions on MSE sometimes not work for questions on MO?

Tags: discussion, mathjax, mathoverflow

Perhaps there's something wrong with my computer or mathoverflow, but I just would like to point out that I can't just copy my question from MSE to MO. When I do that, the Latex sometimes does not work for mathematical equations, while it sometimes does work for plain text. (i.e. it 'texifies' text I don't want to be texified). The latex is perfectly visible the way I want it on MSE, but not on MO.

What is the reason for this? Do MO and MSE process the latex slightly differently?
This is about my last question on tetration and real iteration of a function.

Max

(by the way, please take a look at the afore-mentioned question. I hope not only it's code gets a bit more attention :)!  )

EDIT: here's where the question starts to become messy on MO:

$$b^{(b)}_x = 1 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(\log(b))^n}{n!}b^{(b)n}_{x-1}.\qquad \text{(1)}$$

Comment: MO and math.SE process regular text slightly differently, which leads to a slight difference in how they process LaTeX as well.  It would have been a good idea for you to copy-paste the offending bit of text; my guess is it has something to do with escaping special characters.

Comment: @ Qiaochu Yuan: I will copy the offending bit of text, good idea.

Comment: Please discuss MO problems on http://meta.mathoverflow.net/. I'm closing it as Off Topic.

Comment: @Kenny: It was **wrong** to close this question. It is important that there be synergy between MO and here. Anything that helps to promote such synergy such as compatibilities that promote reuse of LaTeX makes it easier for experts to move back-and-forth between the two sites. Please reopen the question.

Comment: @Bill: OP's main concern is MO's MathJax doesn't work the same as ours, which we can do nothing since it's not administrated by us. It's like asking your MATH-321 instructor how to do your MATH-304 homework, because "there should be synergy between among the department". If OP wants MO follow math.SE's behavior, [file a feature-request meta.MO](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/2/); if OP wants math.SE follow MO's behavior, [there is already a duplicate](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/551); if OP wants synergy between the 2 sites, create a new discussion. I won't reopen this.

Comment: The OP is not requesting any features here.  This is a true *question* -- i.e., he wants to understand better the subtle differences in the way LaTeX works on the two sites.  I think this is a helpful, constructive question and I have voted to reopen it.

Comment: Cast the final vote to reopen. I honestly do not understand your point, KennyTM, and I would think that reserving the usage of the unilateral powers given by moderatorship to situations that merit it would be the best strategy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with the offending bit of text is that MO processes underscores differently from math.SE.  You need to escape the underscores.  One way to do this on MO is by putting `` around all of your $\LaTeX$.

Comment: By the way, it's not just that *the preview* processes things differently on math.SE and on MO. Both previews are correct in the sense that they show you what you would get if you posted. On math.SE, the server [doesn't allow markdown inside dollar signs](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/551/allow-texification-in-code-tags/1119#1119), but MO runs on SE 1.0 which lacks this handy feature.